# Get the right Touchposition on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch, mouse

I have a site where you can draw on a fluid canvas.

I get the right position for the mouse with this code:

```
  function getMouesPosition(e) {
    var mouseX = e.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth | 0;
    var mouseY = e.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight | 0;
    return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
  }
```

But I don't get the right position with a tochevent. How can I  get it?
All I found doesn't work right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `touchstart` event for this.

Here is how you can grab the coordinates from this event:

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    let touches = e.touches[0]
    console.log(touches.clientX, touches.clientY)
})
```

Just remember that you can have multiple touches from the e.touches array.